# TinyMCE table don´t show

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i have TinyMCE editor and every plugin works fine (like bold, italic, align, list) but when i create a table (8x8 or whatever table) and create a article, it don´t show the table (and don´t save it to the database). Other plugins work fine.

I have text type in database (where i put all from textarea).

What´s the problem?

```
<textarea name="content" rows="6" cols="35"></textarea>

<script>
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    width: "auto",
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link table", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your minimal code example that isn't working.

Comment: I think code is working fine, because it saves the text (and formated text too, with plugin (bold, italic, list)) into the database, but don´t save the table

Comment: If the table's HTML is in TinyMCE but not saved to the database the issue is with your code that processes the posted data (not TinyMCE).